# Python multiprocessing imported class pickling error

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, .so

For a project I'm working on I need to work with classes in compiled files, and I don't understand the error I get when using the multiprocessing module.

I kept getting errors, so I greatly simplified what I was working with but realized even the simplest implementation gave the same error.

I tried to run the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from structures.target import Target



def get_lat(tar: Target)->float:
    return tar.x_coord  
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create target_list of Target objects
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    lat_list = pool.map(get_lat, target_list)
```

Where the Target class is imported from the file

```
target.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

in the structures directory contained in the directory from where the script is run.

As far as I've understood, everything passed onto pool.map has to be pickleable, which I thought was the case since they seem to be defined at low-level. Yet I still get the following error:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'compiled.structures.target.Target'>: import of module 'compiled.structures.target' failed
```

I don't understand why importing the compiled file failed, since running this :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create target_list of Target objects
    l = [tar.x_coord for tar in target_list]
```

works perfectly. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `target_list`  is a list of `Target` objects? You could create 1 Target and see if its picklable. `pickle.dumps(Target(..))`. C extensions usually implement `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods if they want to be picklable. You don't show how these targets are initialized. You may be better off passing in the parameters to build `Target` instead of the objects themselves.

Comment: If you don't mind being linux/mac only, you can put `target_list` into a global variable and then just pass the `range(len(my_global_target_list))` into the map function. Since linux/mac multiprocessing uses copy-on-write, you'll have a view of the data in the children.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! I tried pickling a single Target object and it is indeed not pickleable, or at least I get exactly the same error about the import failure. I would like to work with these objects though because they have more functionality than the data inside them, is there anything I can do ?

Comment: Can you instantiate them in the child worker function? Suppose its instantiated with a few integers, `Targe(1,2,3)` for instance. You could pass `[(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]` in map and have the worker build `Target`. If you are linux/mac only, there is a way.

Comment: Yes that works ! The program works as expected, although after running it I get an ignored Exception :  `Exception ignored in: <function Pool.__del__ at 0x7f45d7ace040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in __del__
  File ".../python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 362, in put
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dumps'`

So I still don't fully understand, but at least it works as I hoped it would. Thanks a lot for your time !